# Dell Inspiron 14(3421) running Windows 7 Pro as default primary OS and Ubuntu as secondary OS?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows

I have a very legit query, 
My Dell Inspiron 14(3421) system came pre-installed with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS as the Primary OS on the whole disk drive(no partitions were made). So I made a recovery/backup disk of the Dell Ubuntu System and then formatted the whole system. I partitioned the disk to setup Win 7 Pro and now Win 7 Pro 64bit is perfectly loaded as the Primary OS. Now I want Ubuntu 12.04 LTS/12.10 to be installed as the Secondary OS. How do I do that PERFECTLY?
So what do I do now? :)
A response to this would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This site works best when there's one question per post. I've edited out your other questions. Feel free to repost them as separate new questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately its not possible to do the old 'install the bootloader to a specific partition' trick on ubuntu. The 'best' way to do what you want is to install ubuntu, let it overwrite the bootloader that windows installed, then reinstall the bootloader with something like [easybcd](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) (hit 'see plans' for the free version). This should set up the windows bootloader as the main bootloader, and windows 7 as the first option, and the linux bootloader as a secondary option.